# Concat two values using sqlldr throws error

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-loader

I have a table to which i want to load data using sqlldr,
The DDL of the table is as below,

```
create table abc.AccountDataDump (
CIF_ID  varchar2(20),
ACCOUNT_NO varchar2(30),
TURNOVER number(15,2),
CASH_WITHDRAWAL number(15,2),
CASH_DEPOSIT number(15,2),
MONTH number(2),
YEAR number(4) );
```

I have the ctl file as below,

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE '/home/sijo/Downloads/testcash/CXPS_CASHDATA_MONTHLY_APR21.TXT' 
 badfile '/home/sijo/Downloads/testcash/cash.bad' 
 discardfile '/home/sijo/Downloads/testcash/cash.rej' 
 TRUNCATE INTO TABLE CXPSADM_sijo_47z50.AccountDataDump 
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '~|' 
 TRAILING NULLCOLS 
 ( 
  "CIF_ID", 
  "ACCOUNT_NO" "A_F_||:ACCOUNT_NO", 
  "TURNOVER", 
  "CASH_WITHDRAWAL", 
  "CASH_DEPOSIT" , 
  "MONTH" , 
  "YEAR" 
 )
```

Basically i am  trying to prepend 'A_F_' to the "ACCOUNT_NO" but it is throwing the error as below. The account number in the in file is proper

```
"Record 1: Rejected - Error on table CXPSADM_SIJO_47Z50.ACCOUNTDATADUMP, column "ACCOUNT_NO".
ORA-00984: column not allowed here"
```

If i replace `"ACCOUNT_NO" "A_F_||:ACCOUNT_NO"`, with just `"ACCOUNT_NO"`, then it is working fine. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
"ACCOUNT_NO" "A_F_||:ACCOUNT_NO",
```

by

```
ACCOUNT_NO "'A_F_'||:ACCOUNT_NO",
```

Let me show you how it works

**Demo**

```
[ftpfdm@scglvdoracd0006 ~]$ cat t.ctl
LOAD DATA
INFILE '/home/ftpfdm/t.dat'
 badfile '/home/ftpfdm/t.bad'
 discardfile '/home/ftpfdm/t.dsc'
 TRUNCATE INTO TABLE TEST1.LOADER_EXAMPLE
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
 TRAILING NULLCOLS
 (
  CIF_ID,
  ACCOUNT_NO "'A_F_'||:ACCOUNT_NO"
 )

[ftpfdm@scglvdoracd0006 ~]$ cat t.dat
1;A2
2;B2
[ftpfdm@scglvdoracd0006 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Sep 1 11:37:12 2021
Version 19.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0

SQL> truncate table test1.loader_Example ;

Table truncated.

SQL> desc test1.loader_example
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 CIF_ID                                             NUMBER
 ACCOUNT_NO                                         VARCHAR2(50)

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0
[ftpfdm@scglvdoracd0006 ~]$ sqlldr control=t.ctl
Username:/ as sysdba

SQL*Loader: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Sep 1 11:37:32 2021
Version 19.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Conventional
Commit point reached - logical record count 2

Table TEST1.LOADER_EXAMPLE:
  2 Rows successfully loaded.

Check the log file:
  t.log
for more information about the load.
[ftpfdm@scglvdoracd0006 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Sep 1 11:37:40 2021
Version 19.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0

SQL> select * from test1.loader_example ;

    CIF_ID ACCOUNT_NO
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 A_F_A2
         2 A_F_B2

SQL>
```

Comment: After replacing it gives the below error,   SQL*Loader-466: Column "A_F_||:ACCOUNT_NO" does not exist in table CXPSADM_SIJO_47Z50.ACCOUNTDATADUMP.

Comment: check the edit post, I was just putting the transformation code.

Comment: "ACCOUNT_NO" "'A_F_' || :ACCOUNT_NO",  --> same error as Record 9: Rejected - Error on table CXPSADM_SIJO_47Z50.ACCOUNTDATADUMP, column "ACCOUNT_NO".
ORA-00984: column not allowed here. Actually i had put that only but in logs it shows like this  Column Name                  Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype

"CIF_ID"                            FIRST     *           CHARACTER
    Terminator string : '~|'
"ACCOUNT_NO"                         NEXT     *           CHARACTER
    Terminator string : '~|'
    SQL string for column : "A_F_ || :ACCOUNT_NO"

Comment: Same error is coming after enclosing 'A_F_' in sigle quotes

Comment: I put a demo in the answer. It works, follow the same logic I used